# ValueError: unconverted data remains: +00:00

Tags: android, python, eve

i'm trying to build an API using eve.
All is good when i test my api using 'POSTMAN', but when i use android application i have this log at PyCharm.
i'm using Volley as HTTP library. 
thank you for help

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2016 10:37:29] "GET /accounts HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/flaskapp.py", line 946, in __call__
    return super(Eve, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/endpoints.py", line 54, in collections_endpoint
    response = get(resource, lookup)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/methods/common.py", line 242, in rate_limited
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/auth.py", line 79, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/methods/common.py", line 944, in decorated
    r = f(resource, **combined_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/methods/get.py", line 92, in get
    req = parse_request(resource)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/utils.py", line 155, in parse_request
    r.if_modified_since = weak_date(headers.get('If-Modified-Since'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/utils.py", line 174, in weak_date
    timedelta(seconds=1) if date else None
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 340, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: +00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the client is sending an invalid date in the `If-Modified-Since` header, i.e. the date does not conform to the format described in [RFC 1123](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1). An example of that format is

```
Sun, 08 May 2016 10:00:00 GMT
```

Possibly a date like this is being sent by the client, i.e. Volley:

```
Sun, 08 May 2016 10:00:00 GMT+00:00
```

`eve` can't handle that because it parses times using this format string:

```
RFC1123_DATE_FORMAT = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'
```

It's not clear where the invalid timezone value is originating. Looking at the `volley` code, it will accept and propagate timezones such as `GMT+00:00`, but it will not generate them. Similarly the `eve` code will not generate them.

Possibly your API is somehow returning a date with `+00:00`, and then volley echos that value in the next request to your API? Or, maybe it's originating in the android app.

I would concentrate on identifying the source of the invalid date. Try dumping out the request headers in eve/flask, and do the same in volley if possible.

Comment: i tried to change the device date and the header and the PC date but no luck but when i changed the library everything works fine i think that it's a problem with volley not with the rest api cause i tested it using postman and it's working